# Rasperry Pi import error: No module named xxxxxx

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a raspberry-pi project and getting this error:

> import error: No module named Pubnub

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do and when/where you're seeing the error?

Comment: what basically i've to do is i want my pir sensor to sense motion and capture picture using my rpi cam. But when i execute the file i see this error

Comment: What's the command you used to generate the error? What operating system?

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python PirCam.py
  File "PirCam.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Pubnub import Pubnub
ImportError: No module named Pubnub

Comment: Quick googling suggests that you are trying to follow instructions at https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-06-30-create-realtime-raspberry-pi-security-camera-w-parse/ but you need to tell us which parts of that you have done, and where you are stuck. Without context, all we can tell is that "your computer is broken". If you want help, you'll have to tell us much more.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are new to Python programming,and that you have found a script in a google search result and have copied and pasted it (or similar) on to your Raspberry Pi.

The import statement is a mechanism by which your code is able to access code in a different module. In order for this to work, Python has to be able to find that module on your Pi - the error indicates that it was unable to do this.

Typically this is because you need to download the package (a bit like a directory) which includes that module (a bit like a file). So go back to wherever you got that Python script from - you should be able to find information on the package that you need to download.